# Why are SVG images not displaying when linked from blob storage?

Tags: html, azure, svg, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I have a blazor WASM site, and I am trying to display an SVG image directly from blob storage.  I have tried using

```
<img src="https://rmssdstorage.blob.core.windows.net/mixandswirlimages/cbf53722-5889-4100-8c2e-30b8500e1a3d.svg" height="300"/>
```

but this results in a broken image link.  You can see that this image is there on the server: you are able to download it by clicking on the link: https://rmssdstorage.blob.core.windows.net/mixandswirlimages/cbf53722-5889-4100-8c2e-30b8500e1a3d.svg

I've also tried using

`<object type="image/svg+xml" src="https://rmssdstorage.blob.core.windows.net/mixandswirlimages/cbf53722-5889-4100-8c2e-30b8500e1a3d.svg"></object>`

but this seems to cause the image to download to your device (but will still not cause it to be displayed on the page).

If I link to an image from another source, it DOES display:

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Aperiodisk-v%C3%A4xelstorhet.svg" height="300" />
```

Why is it that I can display images from other sites, but cannot display them from my Azure CDN Blob Storage, even though these images are publicly accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you might need to set the content-type of the blob. By default it is `application/octet-stream`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103396/2170938

Comment: Thank you.  This was indeed the issueand now that I know this is the issue I was able to set this property in my code: 
`if (isSVG) { buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file);//SVGs are stored as plaintext. var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer); fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/svg+xml"); form.Add(fileContent, "image", fileName); await Http.PostAsync("api/HttpStreamReceiver", form); } `

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the steps below:

Go to azure portal -> your storage account -> in the left blade, click `Storage Explorer (preview)` -> then find the .svg image -> right click it and select `Properties` -> in the `Blob Properties` page, check the `ContentType`: if it's not `image/svg+xml`, please set it as `image/svg+xml`, then click `Save` button.

Here is a screenshot of the steps:

[image]

By the way, you can also use the [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows) to do that.

Comment: Thank you.  This does get the image to display, and now that I know this is the issue I was able to set this property in my code:

` if (isSVG)
                {
                    buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file);//SVGs are stored as plaintext.
                    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
                    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/svg+xml");
                    form.Add(fileContent, "image", fileName);
                    await Http.PostAsync("api/HttpStreamReceiver", form);
                }`